# My while loop runs forever when I input an input that isn't one of my options

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello, and welcome to my game of Quartz Parchment and Shears"
                        + " (AKA Rock Paper Scizzors)!"
                        + "\n\nType quartz, parchment or shears!\n");

    //The description and instructions for the game.

    boolean valid = false;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = userInput.next();

    //This code asks for the user input.

    while (!valid) {

    switch (s) {

        case "Quartz":
            System.out.println("\nYou have picked quartz!");
                valid = true;
                break;
        case "Parchment":
            System.out.println("\nYou have picked parchment!");
                valid = true;
                break;
        case "Shears":
            System.out.println("\nYou have picked shears!");
                valid = true;
                break;
        default:
            System.out.println("\nInput not recognised, please try again!");
                valid = false;
                break;
                }
                    }

    userInput.close();

    //This code ensures the user selects a valid option.

    ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        response.add("Quartz");
        response.add("Parchment");
        response.add("Shears");

        Random random = new Random();
        int value = random.nextInt(3);

        String ai = response.get(value);

    switch (ai) {

        case "Quartz":
            System.out.println("\nYour opponent has picked quartz!");
                break;
        case "Parchment":
            System.out.println("\nYour opponent has picked parchment!");
                break;
        case "Shears":
            System.out.println("\nYour opponent has picked shears!");
                break;

                    }

    //This code randomly selects the program's choice.

    if (ai == s) {
        System.out.println("Draw!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Quartz") && ai.equals("Shears")) {

            System.out.println("\nYou win!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Quartz") && ai.equals("Parchment")) {

            System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Parchment") && ai.equals("Shears")) {

        System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Parchment") && ai.equals("Quartz")) {

        System.out.println("\nYou win!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Shears") && ai.equals("Quartz")) {

    System.out.println("\nYou lose!");
    }
    else if (s.equals("Shears") && ai.equals("Parchment")) {

    System.out.println("\nYou win!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nYou draw!");
        }   

    //This code decides and declares the winner.

    }
}
```

I'm not sure why, when I input Quartz, Parchment or Shears the program runs fine. However, when I enter anything else, the program spams "Input not recognised, please try again!" forever. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move the `userInput.next()` part inside the loop.

Comment: you need to have userInput.next() within the loop

Comment: Well you have `!valid` as the condition of stopping the loop.  So if valid is false, that is true; meaning it will run forever.  You need a `userInput.next()` in that loop to get a new user input to break that loop.

Comment: More importantly, you need to use the *result* of `userInput.next()` to assign a new value to `s` (or `t` - it's not clear why you've got both variables, really).

Comment: @resueman I had to move it out of the loop to fix another problem, i'm not sure how to fix this and the other thing. I'll put the rest of my code in.

Comment: @sidgate I updated the post to show the rest of my code, if Ii did that then the lasp part of my code won't be able to see the s, is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: `if(ai == s)` **Don't do this!** Instead, do `if( ai.equals(s) )`. Even though this doesn't pertain to the question, it will help you later down the road when you encounter a bug with this line.

Comment: @Susannah PottsI updated the post to show the rest of my code, if Ii did that then the lasp part of my code won't be able to see the s, is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: The declaration `String s = ""` of your variable needs to stay where it is now  and you need to include `s = userInput.next();` inside of your loop

Comment: Why wouldn't this monolithic main not be able to see s if you update it in that loop?

Comment: @sidgate I mean, I need the String s = userInput.next() part outside the loop so that my if/else if/else section of code at the end can interact with the variable s, but I also apparently need the String s = userInput.next() inside the loop to prevent the recurring loop. How do I do both?

Answer (score 0):

When your input is neither **Quartz**, **Parchment**, **Shears**,the default of switch case will be executed.so here you are assign fasle to value( **value=false**).So when compiler again checks the condition,the condition is found to be true,and again default case is executedand this keeps going on.This is causing infinite loop

Comment: should also be noted to solve, in the default case just put another line `s = userInput.next();` after setting `valid = false;`

Comment: true or s=userInput.next(); can be declared outside switch() but inside while loop.

Comment: No it cannot do that unfortunately. If you declare outside `switch` statement, that means even if he enters correct input such as "Quartz", it will break out of the `switch` statement and then ask for new input. It must be in the default case in this example.

Comment: when the input is "Quartz",value will be set to true and while loop's condition becomes false and so it will also exit the loop also with it.

Comment: No, it will not if you have the `s=userInput.next()` statement at the bottom after the `switch` statement. I encourage you to test this using a debugger. It _MUST_ go in the default case with the code provided. Otherwise the user will be prompted for new input, in which they could input invalid information and it will exit the while loop